# wsgi: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django' error

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I am trying to host my Django app on my Ubuntu server and when trying to access my website, I get this error from the Apache log:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
```

I am using a venv for my Django app with python version 3.8 (I have also compiled and installed mod_wsgi in my venv).
Running pip freeze I see that I do have Django installed in my venv:

```
APScheduler==3.8.1
asgiref==3.5.0
backports.zoneinfo==0.2.1
certifi==2021.10.8
charset-normalizer==2.0.10
colorama==0.4.4
commonmark==0.9.1
deepdiff==5.7.0
Django==4.0.1
django-cors-headers==3.11.0
djangorestframework==3.13.1
idna==3.3
lxml==4.7.1
mod-wsgi==4.9.1.dev1
ordered-set==4.0.2
prettytable==3.0.0
psycopg2-binary==2.9.3
Pygments==2.11.2
pytz==2021.3
pytz-deprecation-shim==0.1.0.post0
requests==2.27.1
rich==11.1.0
six==1.16.0
soupsieve==2.3.1
sqlparse==0.4.2
tzdata==2021.5
tzlocal==4.1
urllib3==1.26.8
wcwidth==0.2.5
whitenoise==5.3.0
```

And just in case it might solve it, I installed Django globally but still got the error in Apache. I have been trying to follow some of the common solutions but can't seem to get it to work. Is there anything I am missing or any setting that may be off?

I do notice my Apache says it is configured with 3.6, could this be the cause? is there a way to make it use 3.8 which is my python3 default?

**My wsgi** for my Django project (backend/core/wsgi.py):

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append('/home/brickmane/djangoapp/pricewatcher/backend/')

sys.path.append('/home/brickmane/djangoapp/pricewatcher/backend/core/')
sys.path.append('/home/brickmane/djangoapp/pricewatcher/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages')


from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'core.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

**My virtualhost** settings in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:

```
WSGIPythonHome /home/brickmane/djangoapp/pricewatcher/venv
WSGIPythonPath /home/brickmane/djangoapp/pricewatcher/backend
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAlias www.d8pricecheck.tk

  WSGIProcessGroup backend

  Alias /static/ /home/brickmane/djangoapp/pricewatcher/backend/static/

  <Directory /home/brickmane/djangoapp/pricewatcher/backend/static>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  WSGIScriptAlias / /home/brickmane/djangoapp/pricewatcher/backend/core/wsgi.py
  
  <Directory /home/brickmane/djangoapp/pricewatcher/backend/core>
    <Files wsgi.py>
      Require all granted
    </Files>
  </Directory>
 WSGIDaemonProcess backend python-path=/home/brickmane/djangoapp/pricewatcher/backend/core python-home=/home/brickmane/djangoapp/pricewatcher/venv
 WSGIProcessGroup backend
</VirtualHost>
```

Full Apache error log from restarting and visiting website:

```
   [Tue Feb 01 16:24:09.488925 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 30163] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
    [Tue Feb 01 16:24:09.618015 2022] [ssl:warn] [pid 30456] AH01916: Init: (brickmaneserver.hsd1.ga.comcast.net:443) You configured HTTP(80) on the standard HTTPS(443) port!
    [Tue Feb 01 16:24:09.696360 2022] [ssl:warn] [pid 30459] AH01916: Init: (brickmaneserver.hsd1.ga.comcast.net:443) You configured HTTP(80) on the standard HTTPS(443) port!
    [Tue Feb 01 16:24:09.702058 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 30459] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.1g mod_wsgi/4.5.17 Python/3.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
    [Tue Feb 01 16:24:09.702100 2022] [core:notice] [pid 30459] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
    [Tue Feb 01 16:24:11.607243 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 30490] [remote 27.147.213.242:33593] mod_wsgi (pid=30490): Target WSGI script '/home/brickmane/djangoapp/myserver/backend/core/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
    [Tue Feb 01 16:24:11.607289 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 30490] [remote 27.147.213.242:33593] mod_wsgi (pid=30490): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/brickmane/djangoapp/myserver/backend/core/wsgi.py'.
    [Tue Feb 01 16:24:11.607468 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 30490] [remote 27.147.213.242:33593] Traceback (most recent call last):
    [Tue Feb 01 16:24:11.607495 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 30490] [remote 27.147.213.242:33593]   File "/home/brickmane/djangoapp/myserver/backend/core/wsgi.py", line 21, in <module>
    [Tue Feb 01 16:24:11.607502 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 30490] [remote 27.147.213.242:33593]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
    [Tue Feb 01 16:24:11.607520 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 30490] [remote 27.147.213.242:33593] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
    [Tue Feb 01 16:24:14.525726 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 30490] [remote 108.162.238.29:17852] mod_wsgi (pid=30490): Target WSGI script '/home/brickmane/djangoapp/myserver/backend/core/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
    [Tue Feb 01 16:24:14.525891 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 30490] [remote 108.162.238.29:17852] mod_wsgi (pid=30490): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/brickmane/djangoapp/myserver/backend/core/wsgi.py'.
    [Tue Feb 01 16:24:14.526144 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 30490] [remote 108.162.238.29:17852] Traceback (most recent call last):
    [Tue Feb 01 16:24:14.526242 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 30490] [remote 108.162.238.29:17852]   File "/home/brickmane/djangoapp/myserver/backend/core/wsgi.py", line 21, in <module>
    [Tue Feb 01 16:24:14.526266 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 30490] [remote 108.162.238.29:17852]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
    [Tue Feb 01 16:24:14.526327 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 30490] [remote 108.162.238.29:17852] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
    [Tue Feb 01 16:24:14.810004 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 30490] [remote 162.158.187.159:17484] mod_wsgi (pid=30490): Target WSGI script '/home/brickmane/djangoapp/myserver/backend/core/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
    [Tue Feb 01 16:24:14.810169 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 30490] [remote 162.158.187.159:17484] mod_wsgi (pid=30490): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/brickmane/djangoapp/myserver/backend/core/wsgi.py'.
    [Tue Feb 01 16:24:14.810397 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 30490] [remote 162.158.187.159:17484] Traceback (most recent call last):
    [Tue Feb 01 16:24:14.810484 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 30490] [remote 162.158.187.159:17484]   File "/home/brickmane/djangoapp/myserver/backend/core/wsgi.py", line 21, in <module>
    [Tue Feb 01 16:24:14.810506 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 30490] [remote 162.158.187.159:17484]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
    [Tue Feb 01 16:24:14.810566 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 30490] [remote 162.158.187.159:17484] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to install in venv Python version at least 3.8, because 3.7 and lower are not compatible with Django 4.0+. You should delete venv completely and reinitialize with installed Python with newer (newest is 3.10.2) version.

If Ubuntu has at least 3.8, then it should be fine. If not, try to install/upgrade it.
Here you have some hints how to do it: https://cloudbytes.dev/snippets/upgrade-python-to-latest-version-on-ubuntu-linux

Comment: My python version in my venv is 3.8 and my global python3 is 3.8 as well. I installed 3.6 before which is why I think apache is configured to that version. I don't know if that is whats causing the issue but if it is how can I set apache to use 3.8? Could I reinstall it? Would that remove my settings in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf?

Comment: I am not sure if reinstall mod_wsgi will interfere with apache's *.conf file, but it's possible. Better make copy. Well, actually you have a copy in this post :)

Comment: I don't really know where I have stuff in there and I don't want to break the static websites I have up now and their settings if possible. I tried to reinstall mod_wsgi but that didnt work either

Comment: I don't think I can help you with Apache then, sorry.

Comment: Appreciate the help I'll keep at it. If I can't figure it out I might backup what I can and try to reinstall Apache and see if it will use 3.8. I'm not sure if it being 3.6 configured means the mod wsgi is made for 3.6? I'm wondering if it checks what python version my apache is using / configured to and builds it for that. in this case 3.6 because its configured to it

Comment: I have similar problem. I've got Python 3.7 at my Raspberry Pi and I cannot upgrade Django to 4.0. I've lazily decided, that I don't need upgrade, because I'm not updating the application there anyway. You can try degrading Django to 3.9, but it's not definitely a final solution.

Answer (score 0):

This question is bit old, but if someone still faces this. I have solved this by setting the **python-path** to my **python's site-packages**. Also for your case above

```
WSGIDaemonProcess backend python-path=/home/brickmane/djangoapp/pricewatcher/venv/lib/python
3.8/site-packages python-home=/home/brickmane/djangoapp/pricewatcher/venv
```

This solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

For me, I determined that Apache2 mod_wsgi was compiled against python 3.9 and my django instance was using python 3.10.

```
ldd /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe32535000)
libpython3.9.so.1.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.9.so.1.0 (0x00007f9c59b77000)
. . .
```

Making sure my system Python was also set to 3.9 fixed this error.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue, the problem boiled down to having 2 different gunicorn installations (one global and one in the virtual environment). When running the global installation was being preferenced but it not being in the right path was unable to find Django. Deactivated virtual environment, uninstalled the global, reactivated the virtual env. Now runs fine. Hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Just use sudo when you install requirements.txt or other packages. for example :
instead of pip install -r requirements.txt use this
sudo pip install -r requirements.txt
or
instead of pip install django use
sudo pip install django

Comment: It is generally not recommended to install pip packages as root. This might break some stuff other users have made on the machine. Rather you should install the packages in a virtual environment