# Make Apache use Python3.8 instead of 3.6?

Tags: python, apache, apache2

I am trying to get my django app hosted and keep running into errors.

Someone mentioned my apache version is configured to python3.6 and it should match my venv version which is 3.8. I have also set 3.8 to be global default for python3.

How can I make apache use 3.8?
In the log it says 3.6 which is the version I think I had when I set it up.

```
[Tue Feb 01 16:39:08.283534 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 30860] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.1g mod_wsgi/4.5.17 Python/3.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get mod\_wsgi to pick up my virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42661771/how-to-get-mod-wsgi-to-pick-up-my-virtualenv)

Comment: No I tried to uninstall and reinstall the different versions of mod-wsgi and I did try to add my venv path to both my wsgi.py and virtual host settings. If you are familiar with wsgi / apache and django could you take a look here and see if you can see what I am doing wrong? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70947944/wsgi-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-django-error/70948207?noredirect=1#comment125423670_70948207 
This is the problem I was having that led me to try to change my apache python config